# how to add image as a header in angular ui grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like to add image in the header, not in the rows.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.gridOptions = {
   enableSorting: true,
   columnDefs: [
     { field: 'name' },
     { field: 'company'  },
     { field: '<THIS NEEDS TO BE IMAGE>' displayName: 'Timer'}
   ],
   data:[
     {name:"Name1",company:"Company1",Timer:"10"},
     {name:"Name2",company:"Company2",Timer:"11"},]
};  
}]);
```

Comment: Can you include your template to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific example to paste in but I would assume that you could override the default **headerCellTemplate**.  I have used cellTemplate with an image but not headerCellTemplate.  Given all the other features that can show up in the header, you may have to find the default headerCellTemplate then add your image.

Answer (score 0):

Like @WadeB mentioned, you have to use a `headerCellTemplate` for that specific column.

I created [a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aPNqaeG2C04f9FsYeYPp?p=preview) showcasing a possible setup.

You need to add the headerCellTemplate to your columnDef:

```
{ field: 'company', headerCellTemplate: myHeader}
```

and create your own template by creating a local variable:

```
var myHeader = "<div ng-class=\"{ 'sortable': sortable }\"><!-- <div class=\"ui-grid-vertical-bar\">&nbsp;</div> --><div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" col-index=\"renderIndex\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><span>{{ col.displayName CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</span> <span ui-grid-visible=\"col.sort.direction\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }\">&nbsp;</span></div><div class=\"ui-grid-column-menu-button\" ng-if=\"grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false\" ng-click=\"toggleMenu($event)\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-column-menu-button-last-col': isLastCol}\"><i class=\"ui-grid-icon-angle-down\">&nbsp;</i></div><div ui-grid-filter></div></div>"
```

Thats a bit messy to understand, the important part is:

```
{{ col.displayName CUSTOM_FILTERS }}
```

Replace that part with anything you'd like, for example a picture like shown in the Plunkr

```
var myHeader = "<div ng-class=\"{ 'sortable': sortable }\"><!-- <div class=\"ui-grid-vertical-bar\">&nbsp;</div> --><div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" col-index=\"renderIndex\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><span><img src=\"https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png\" alt=\"Mountain View\" style=\"width:100px;height:30px;\"></span> <span ui-grid-visible=\"col.sort.direction\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }\">&nbsp;</span></div><div class=\"ui-grid-column-menu-button\" ng-if=\"grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false\" ng-click=\"toggleMenu($event)\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-column-menu-button-last-col': isLastCol}\"><i class=\"ui-grid-icon-angle-down\">&nbsp;</i></div><div ui-grid-filter></div></div>";
```

You could also override the template globally:

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/uiGridHeaderCell',
    '<div>my-own-html</div>'
);
```